# Who sets the skin? Bungeecord or Spigot

Tags: bukkit, bungeecord

I'm working on a nick plugin for my network. I managed to change the name of the player. Really... It changes everywhere on the spigot server. Eaven other plugins don't get the real name.
But now I stuck in changing the skin of the player and I have one main question... Who sets the skin? Bungeecord or Spigot. In fact that the Bungeecord server is an online server and all the gameservers are offline servers I think that maybe the bungeecord-server is able to change the skin of the player. And in that case... Does anyone have a working method? Because I tryed nearly everything I've found in google.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

### Minecraft 1.8 and higher

The skin comes from the Mojang servers, this skin is fetched by Bungeecord at the moment of when the player logins, and is then passed over the connection to Spigot.

Spigot is then responsible for the sending this players skin to the other players on the servers in the form of a `GameProfile` object. If we check what this GameProfile object contains, we will see that it contains a `signature` and a `skin data`, the signature is generated by Mojang at the moment of skin change ad is based on the skin, and the skin data contains the textures used for the skin and cape. If you want to change the skin, you should register a new Minecraft account with the skin you use (or hopefully find a existing account with the skin), and use his skin data and signatures.

### Minecraft 1.7 and lower

In these minecraft versions, the skin is resolved using the player's name. A request is made to `http://minecraft.net/skin/<username>.png`. This will return a simple png file with the skin contents. If you try this method with people who changed their name in 1.8, it will fail, since this service doesn't recognise the 1.8 usernames.

Comment: Also, note that the skin is tied to the UUID, which (hopefully) is kept constant even after the name is changed.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I am not sure if that true, I make a skin swapper plugin with another dev in the past that swapped the skin of 2 people and it worked just fine

Comment: You're right that in the past it was like that, but with the mojang API, [it uses UUIDs](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#UUID_-.3E_Profile_.2B_Skin.2FCape).   The old [skins.minecraft.net API](http://wiki.vg/Minecraft.net) uses names.  IIRC, this change was made in 1.7.10 and 1.8.  (This is based off of what I remember; you might be right but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work like that anymore)

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to change the skin. But now I have a new problem: I work with Scoreboard Teams for the PlayerList and OverHead name. Now I add the name of the fake player to the team. The name over it's head changes, but in the TAB-list, there is a white name of the player. Every player can see, that this is a fake player.

Comment: @NicolaUetz Can you post a new question for this? this way more [tag:bukkit] people will see the question, increasing the odds of a good answer

Comment: Actually, I was wrong - it seems like _is_ sent from the server now (though I strongly remember it being the other way).  [Here's another wiki.vg source](http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Player_List_Item).  Not exactly sure which is which anymore.

Comment: @Pokechu22 if I remember it correctly, it was changed in Minecraft 1.8. The history on the wiki may give more clues